# Валидация в PHP-фреймворке Phalcon

Tags: php, api, framework, rest, phalcon

Пишу небольшой API на PHP используя фреймворк phalcon.
Я новичок в PHP и phalcon, не всё сразу мне понятно.
Вопрос в следующем.
Есть некий простенький роут:

```
$app->post('/api/add', function() use ($app) {
    $params = $app->request->getJsonRawBody();

    $phql = "INSERT INTO test (test1, test2) VALUES (:test1:, :test2:)";

    $status = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql, array(
            'test1' => $params->test1,
            'test2' => $params->test2
    ));

    $response = new Phalcon\Http\Response();
    if ($status->success() == true) {
            $response->setStatusCode(201, "Created");
            $response->setJsonContent(array('status' => 'OK', 'data' => $params));

    } else {
            $response->setStatusCode(409, "Conflict");
            $errors = array();
            foreach ($status->getMessages() as $message) {
                    $errors[] = $message->getMessage();
            }
            $response->setJsonContent(array('status' => 'ERROR', 'messages' => $errors));
    }
    return $response;
});
```

Модель, упрощенно, следующая (model.php):

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
class test extends Model {
    public function validation() {
    $this->validate(new Uniqueness(
            array(
        "field"   => "test1",
        "message" => "test1 must be unique"
            )));

        if ($this->validationHasFailed() == true) {
                        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Валидатор работает как положено.

Суть вопроса в том, что таблиц (моделей) у меня несколько и писать каждый раз такой валидатор как-то не очень красиво и захламляет код:

```
$this->validate(new Uniqueness(
    array(
        "field"   => "test1",
        "message" => "test1 must be unique"
            )));
```

Я написал новый класс (validation.php) с содержимым:

```
use Phalcon\Validation,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Regex,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\InclusionIn,
    Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Between,
    Phalcon\Validation\Message;

class check_functions extends Validation
{
    public function checkUnique($field){
            $this->add($field,new Uniqueness(
            array(
                    "message" => "$field must be unique"
            )));
    }

    public function checkRegexp($field,$regexp){
            $this->add($field,new Regex(
            array(
                    "pattern" => $regexp,
                    "message" => "$field is invalid"
            )));
    }
}
```

Вызываю его и использую для нескольких моделей:
model.php:

```
require ('validation.php');
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
....
$check = new check_functions();
$check->checkUnique("test1");
$check->checkRegexp("test1","/^\d+$/");
....
```

Однако этот способ не работает. Код выполняется, возможно что-то и проверяется, но обратного ответа об ошибке ($messages) нет и записи добавляются независимо от передаваемого содержимого.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать один класс-валидатор и использовать его функции для всех новых моделей, корректно отдавая содержимое сообщения об ошибке при запросе к API, в контексте работы с phalcon.

Answer (score 1):

Советую вынести в trait (только если php >= 5.4):

```
trait MyModelValidation
{
    public function validation() {
        $this->validate(new Uniqueness(
            array(
                "field"   => "test1",
                "message" => "test1 must be unique"
            )));

        if ($this->validationHasFailed() == true) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

И далее в любой модели:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    use MyModelValidation;

    // Далее обычный код модели
}
```

PS: Придерживайтесь camel case в именованиях сущностей. class check_functions - это не очень хорошо